# Convert SQL Date result

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert the result of this query

```
select lo.Get_Date_proche@ivr_U('898989898') D
from dual
```

to this format: `ddmmyyyy`

Right now I get this format: `05/05/2016`

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Looks very product specific...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it. It works:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
      TO_DATE(lo.Get_Date_proche@ivr_U('898989898'),'DD/MM/YYYY'),
      'DDMMYYYY'
  ) 
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Click on the **TICK** symbol to Accept your answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below query works for me

```
select to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') from dual;
```

Replace sysdate with your value

Comment: but I want the result about above query be  like ddmmyyyy

Comment: I tried this : SELECT TO_CHAR(D, 'ddmmyyyy') from (select lo.Get_Date_proche@ivr_U('898989898') D
from dual ) but still doesn't work!!!